# Multiplying in JS not working

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I can't really explain my question but i am trying to create a total dollars on my website.
I am trying to multiply the quantity by the size.

```
function total(){
                var x = document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex;
                var y = document.getElementById("price");
                var z = document.getElementById("price2");
        var z = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
                if ((document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value) == "XS") {
                    y.innerHTML="$"."10.00"*"a";
                    z.value="$"."10.00"*"a";
                } 
                else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value) == "S") {
                    y.innerHTML="$"."12.00"*"a";
                    z.value="$"."12.00"*"a";
                } 
                else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value) == "M") {
                    y.innerHTML="$"."13.00"*"a";
                    z.value="$"."13.50"*"a";
                } 
                else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value) == "L") {
                    y.innerHTML="$"."15.00"*"a";
                    z.value="$"."15.00"*"a";
                }
                else if ((document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].value) == "XL") {
                    y.innerHTML="$"."20.00"*"a";
                    z.value="$"."20.00"*"a";
                }
            };
```

This code makes the program not work altogether.

Any help appreciated, Lachlan

Comment: What is the error? Please link to a jsbin or similar place if possible.

Comment: Use eval function to multiply.

Comment: @AkashAmin–no, don't do that.

Comment: Instead of `var x = document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex;` use `var x = document.getElementById("size").value`.

Comment: @RobG- Is there anything wrong in it? Thank you to let me know about it.

Comment: There is no need for *eval*. It's slow, difficult to debug and just not necessary. The OP is just trying to do some multiplication and output formatted text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't posted a mimial example that displays the issue, but likely one issue is how you're getting the value of *x*:

```
  var x = document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex;
```

that can be replaced with getting the value directly:

```
  var x = document.getElementById("size").value;
```

Then you have:

```
if (x == "XS") {
  ...
} 
  else if (x == "S") {
  ...
```

and so on. But all those *if..else* statements can likely be replaced by [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Then there is code like:

```
  y.innerHTML="$"."10.00"*"a";
  z.value="$"."10.00"*"a";
```

I'm not sure what the dot is for, perhaps you are trying concatenation?

```
  y.innerHTML = "$" + (10.00 * a);
  z.value = "$" + (10.00 * a);
```

where *a* is a value from elsewhere? And if you want two decimal places, then:

```
  y.innerHTML = "$" + (10.00 * a).toFixed(2);
```

Oh, and note that an option can have a value that is different to the displayed text, so you can do:

```
  <option value="13.50">M</option>
```

So now you you can remove the *if..else* blocks and just have:

```
  y.innerHTML = "$" + (x * a).toFixed(2);
```

*x* will be a string, but multiplication will coerce it to a number.

Comment: Sorry im not very good at explaining and i am new to javascript. Thanks this helped alot